# asp.net datasource control parameter outside iframe

Tags: asp.net

Hope someone can help me here, i have been searching for a solution for a few days now but havent't found it.

I have build a page with 2 iframes, SelectCustomer which opens a page in where a dropdownlist lives with customer names and iframecontent in which i load a page by clicking a link. This page has a sqldatasource with a parameter. I want to refer to the dropdownlist in this parameter to filter the select query but i haven't found a way to refer to the dropdownlist outside the iframe "iframecontent".

**This is the page with the iframes:**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Dashboard/Sales/Dashboard_Sales.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Index.aspx.vb" Inherits="Dashboard_Sales_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">

  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

            <iframe
        name="SelectCustomer" 
        src="SelectDebiteur.aspx"
        align="top"
        frameborder="0"
        height="50"
        width="100%"
        marginheight="0"
        marginwidth="0"
        scrolling="auto">
    </iframe>
    <iframe
        name="iframecontent"
        height="500"
        width="100%">
                </iframe>

</body>
</html>
</asp:Content>
```

**This is the page from the first iframe:**

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="SelectDebiteur.aspx.vb" Inherits="Dashboard_Sales_SelectDebiteur" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#DropDownList1").on("change", function () {
        // When the DropDownList selected value has been changed,
        // refresh the other iframed page changing its source
        // adding the value as its query string.
        $("#iframecontent", parent.document).attr("src", "Default.aspx?value=" + $(this).val());

        return true;
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="ListDebiteur" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:FLOSConnectionString2 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [aa-270].cddeb, [ba-001].naamorg AS Debiteur FROM [aa-270] INNER JOIN [ba-001] ON [aa-270].cdorg = [ba-001].cdorg ORDER BY Debiteur"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="ListDebiteur" DataTextField="Debiteur" DataValueField="cddeb">
    </asp:DropDownList>

</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**This is the page which get's loaded in the second iframe:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="ListCustomers" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:FLOSConnectionString2 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [aa-270].cddeb, [ba-001].naamorg AS Debiteur FROM [aa-270] INNER JOIN [ba-001] ON [aa-270].cdorg = [ba-001].cdorg ORDER BY Debiteur"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="ListCustomers" DataTextField="Debiteur" DataValueField="cddeb">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:FLOSConnectionString2 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [va-211].cdorg, [ba-001].naamorg, RTRIM(YEAR([va-211].[datum-lvoor])) + '-' + CASE WHEN RTRIM(MONTH([va-211].[datum-lvoor])) &lt; 10 THEN '0' + RTRIM(MONTH([va-211].[datum-lvoor])) ELSE RTRIM(MONTH([va-211].[datum-lvoor])) END AS Maand, SUM(CASE WHEN [va-211].cdstatus = 'O' THEN [va-211].aanttelev * ([va-211].prijs / [bb-063].prijsper) WHEN [va-211].cdstatus = 'A' THEN [va-211].aantgelev * ([va-211].prijs / [bb-063].prijsper) END) AS Omzet FROM [ba-001] INNER JOIN [va-211] ON [ba-001].cdorg = [va-211].cddeb LEFT OUTER JOIN [bb-063] ON [va-211].cdprodukt = [bb-063].cdprodukt WHERE ([bb-063].cdprijssrt = 'VERK') AND ([va-211].cdstatus = 'O' OR [va-211].cdstatus = 'A') GROUP BY [ba-001].naamorg, RTRIM(YEAR([va-211].[datum-lvoor])) + '-' + CASE WHEN RTRIM(MONTH([va-211].[datum-lvoor])) &lt; 10 THEN '0' + RTRIM(MONTH([va-211].[datum-lvoor])) ELSE RTRIM(MONTH([va-211].[datum-lvoor])) END, [va-211].cdorg HAVING (SUM(CASE WHEN [va-211].cdstatus = 'O' THEN [va-211].aanttelev * ([va-211].prijs / [bb-063].prijsper) WHEN [va-211].cdstatus = 'A' THEN [va-211].aantgelev * ([va-211].prijs / [bb-063].prijsper) END) &gt; 0) AND ([va-211].cdorg = @param1) ORDER BY Maand, [ba-001].naamorg">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList2" Name="param1" PropertyName="Text" DefaultValue="00000739" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" EnableModelValidation="True" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="cdorg" HeaderText="cdorg" SortExpression="cdorg" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="naamorg" HeaderText="naamorg" SortExpression="naamorg" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Maand" HeaderText="Maand" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Maand" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Omzet" HeaderText="Omzet" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Omzet" />
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#E3EAEB" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#C5BBAF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And it's code behind page:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Dashboard_Sales_Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        DropDownList2.SelectedValue = Request.QueryString["value"];
}
}
```

New challenge:

```
<a href="javascript:openPage()" target="iframecontent">Omzet in portefeuille </a> </li>

<scriptsrc="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"         
type="text/javascript"></script>                
            <script type="text/javascript">

                openPage = $(function () {
                    location.href = "Default.aspx?value=" + $("#DropDownList1").val();
                });
</script>
```

Comment: And you won't find a way. Tip: If both iframed pages are on the same domain, you can use Javascript to achieve that.

Comment: Hi Melancia, Could you give me a bit more details here. I'm not that good with javascript. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the solutions is to refresh the second iframed page sending the DropDownList selected value as its query string, using jQuery (to make things easier).

To demonstrate, I'm basically updating a DropDownList on the second iframed page, but you can easily adapt to your needs:

**Main page (where the iframes are placed):**

```
<iframe id="iframe1" width="500" height="200" src="WebForm1.aspx"></iframe>
<iframe id="iframe2" width="500" height="200" src="WebForm2.aspx"></iframe>
```

**First iframed page:**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#ddl1").on("change", function () {
            // When the DropDownList selected value has been changed,
            // refresh the other iframed page changing its source
            // adding the value as its query string.
            $("#iframe2", parent.document).attr("src", "WebForm2.aspx?value=" + $(this).val());

            return true;
        });
    });
</script>

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Option 1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Option 2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

**Second iframed page:**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Option 1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Option 2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        ddl2.SelectedValue = Request.QueryString["value"];
}
```

**UPDATE**

Regarding your question posted on the comments, you can find out what's the second page iframe's src (and subsequently change it) this way:

```
$("#iframe2", parent.document).attr("src", $("#iframe2", parent.document).attr("src") + "?value=" + $(this).val());
```

**UPDATE #2**

As per your request, you want to load the iframe source dynamically, at the page load.
That's how you can achieve this:

**Main page (where the iframes are placed):**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#iframe2").attr("src", "the-page-you-want-to-load-on-this-iframe");
    });
</script>
<iframe id="iframe1" width="500" height="200" src="WebForm1.aspx"></iframe>
<iframe id="iframe2" width="500" height="200"></iframe>
```

**First iframed page:**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#ddl1").on("change", function () {
            var iframe2BaseSrc = $("#iframe2", parent.document).attr("src");

            if (iframe2BaseSrc) {
                iframe2BaseSrc = iframe2BaseSrc.split("?")[0];

                $("#iframe2", parent.document).attr("src", iframe2BaseSrc + "?value=" + $(this).val());
            }
            return true;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I have used your code but when i do a select in ddl1 the page webform2.aspx does not get refreshed. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you set the AutoPostBack="true" on your DropDownList?

Comment: Yes, do it so I can have another look.

Comment: This is the page with the iframes:

Comment: Nothing here. Try again.

Comment: There are some points on your updated post. You seem to be using Master Pages, and on the Content Page you're adding again the doctype, html and head sections. Your iframes don't have an id, so the script the way I wrote, won't work.

Comment: Another detail... If you're really using Master Pages, your controls will have their IDs changed when rendered into HTML. You should look the page source to double check that, and change the script accordingly. Or, just add a CssClass to the DropDownList and attach the event handler using this class as a selector instead of the ID.

Comment: I have added an id to both frames and now it works!!!
I want to try to hide the seconde dropdownlist but that is for next week. I'm off for the weekend now. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: No worries. Have fun. :)

Comment: How would i make webform2.aspx dynamic, meaning i want to find the page name inside the iframe. Can't find it with google.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to open quotes. Try again and if it doesn't work, try to debug it and tell me the error returned.

Comment: OK, now it works but i get this error message:
HTTP Error 404 - File or directory not found.

Comment: Hi Melancia, sorry for the late response. i did nog have time today.
I can't see the url because the page loads in the iframe.

Comment: If you're using FF, you can right click the iframed page and open it in a new tab or window. So you can see it.

Comment: If `.attr("src")` is returning `undefined` it's because you didn't set the value on the page. ie: `<iframe ... src="MyPage.aspx"></iframe>`

Comment: Debug the Javascript code, checking what is returning `$("#iframe2", parent.document).attr("src")`.

Comment: Sorry, but i don't really understand what you what me to do.
Can i set the iframe src when i load the page because i want to load different pages in the iframe.

Comment: What I was trying to do is to check what src was defined on the iframe, so I could concat the value coming from the dropdownlist. This way, you wouldn't have the src hardcoded on the script. It could be anything, as far as you fulfill the src on the page. I'll update the answer to try to work around this other option you want.

Comment: It is not working correctly, when i do a second select on the dropdownlist it just adds ?value=00000022 at the end of the value that is present in the textbox. When i do a third select it looks like this 00000739?value=00001361?value=00001939

Comment: My bad. Forgot to remove previous query strings from the base URL. Check the change to the script on my update.

Comment: But you could have fixed that yourself. It's pretty trivial by just debugging the code. It's there anyway.

Comment: it works now, many thanks for that. I have added a new piece of code to my question, can you perhaps tell me how i can use it correctly.

Comment: If this answer solves your original problem, you should vote it as the solution. Further questions require new posts on the forum, to keep things clear. Thanks!